# SQL statement - get multiple values in one column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, subquery

I have an table with data like these:

```
  id | name | value

    12 | KREA | 3,7 

    13 | KREA | 12.6

    12 | GFR  | 2.2

    13 | GFR  | 1.7
```

Now I want to get the name and value of krea and gfr in one column like this:

```
 id | name1 | value1 | name2 | value2

    12 | KREA  | 3.7    | GFR   | 2.2
```

...

I have tried to make an join but it didn't work.

```
select rps1.id, rps1.name, rps1.value, rps2.id, rps2.name, rps2.value 
  from table1 rps1, table1 rps2 
 where rps1.name like 'KREA' 
    or rps2.name like 'GRFR' and rps1.id = rps2.id
   and crd > '17.07.2019 00:00:00' order by id
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Which RDBMS? Ohh and please stop using implicit joins `... From t1, t2 ...`

Comment: it's an oracle db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this.

```
select
  t1.id,
  t1.name,
  t1.value,
  t2.id,
  t2.name,
  t2.value
from
  (select id, name, value from table1 where name='KREA' and crd > '17.07.2019 00:00:00') t1
join
  (select id, name, value from table1 where name='GFR' and crd > '17.07.2019 00:00:00') t2
        on t1.id = t2.id
order by
  t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The query which you tried is perfectly fine except a few mistakes.

```
rps1.name like 'KREA' 
    or rps2.name like 'GRFR' 
--> need to use AND instead of OR
--> need to use 'GFR' instead of 'GRFR' 

order by id
--> Need to use alias rps1.id
```

-- So your query will go like this:

```
select rps1.id, rps1.name, rps1.value, rps2.id, rps2.name, rps2.value 
  from table1 rps1, table1 rps2 
 where rps1.name like 'KREA' 
    AND rps2.name like 'GFR' and rps1.id = rps2.id
   and crd > '17.07.2019 00:00:00' 
   order by rps1.id
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b4b73a093e955a61accd4e9c9aebea31)

Cheers!!